# Posting to blogger with PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, gmail, blogger

I'm getting problem to to get my php script posting to blogger using client http authentication.

I've followed the tutorial from https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php

Here is my code:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

$user = 'myuserid';
$pass = 'mypassword';
$blogUrl = 'myblog.blogspot.com';
$service = 'blogger';

$gdClient = new Zend_Gdata($client);
$blogID = getBlogId($gdClient, 'http://'.$blogUrl.'/feeds/posts/default');

$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service, null,
        Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::DEFAULT_SOURCE, null, null, 
        Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::CLIENTLOGIN_URI, 'GOOGLE');

function createPublishedPost($gdClient, $myBlogId, $title='Hello, world!', $content='I am blogging on the internet.')
{
    $uri = 'https://www.blogger.com/feeds/' . $myBlogId . '/posts/default';
    echo $uri; // nothing wrongs here.
    $entry = $gdClient->newEntry();
    $entry->title = $gdClient->newTitle($title);
    $entry->content = $gdClient->newContent($content);
    $entry->content->setType('text');

    $createdPost = $gdClient->insertEntry($entry, $uri); // I think the error is here.
    $idText = split('-', $createdPost->id->text);
    $newPostID = $idText[2];

    return $newPostID;
}

function getBlogId($gdClient, $feed)
{
    $gdClient = new Zend_Gdata($client);
    $query = new Zend_Gdata_Query($feed);
    $feed = $gdClient->getFeed($query);
    preg_match('/blog-([0-9]+)/', $feed->id->text, $match);
    if (isset($match[1]))
    {
        return $match[1];
    }
    return false;
}

createPublishedPost($gdClient, $blogID);
```

error message is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 401 User does not have permission to create new post' in /home/content/36/9549036/html/[MYUSER]/Zend/Gdata/App.php:714 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/36/9549036/html/[MYUSER]/Zend/Gdata.php(221): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://www.blo...', Array, '<atom:entry xml...', 'application/ato...', NULL) #1 /home/content/36/9549036/html/[MYUSER]/Zend/Gdata/App.php(905): Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('POST', 'https://www.blo...', Array, '<atom:entry xml...', 'application/ato...') #2 /home/content/36/9549036/html/[MYUSER]/Zend/Gdata/App.php(980): Zend_Gdata_App->post(Object(Zend_Gdata_Entry), 'https://www.blo...', NULL, NULL, Array) #3 /home/content/36/9549036/html/[MYUSER]/test.php(29): Zend_Gdata_App->insertEntry(Object(Zend_Gdata_Entry), 'https://www.blo...') #4 /home/content/36/9549036/html/[MYUSER]/test.php(49): createPublishedPost(Object(Zend_Gdata), '[MYBLOGID]...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/content/36/9549036/html/[MYUSER]/Zend/Gdata/App.php on line 714
```

Has anyone experienced this before?
Is there any working code out there to post blogger with php?

Comment: Are you sure it's not an authentication issue, i.e., incorrect username or password?

Comment: nah im pretty sure its not.. anyway I seem to have found the issue, ill post my fixed thing asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue, it works this way.

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

$user = $_SESSION['BloggerUsername'];
$pass = $_SESSION['BloggerPassword'];
$blogUrl = $_SESSION['BloggerUrl'];
$service = 'blogger';

global $gData, $gBlogId;

$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service, null,
        Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::DEFAULT_SOURCE, null, null, 
        Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::CLIENTLOGIN_URI, 'GOOGLE');

function createPublishedPost($gData, $gBlogId, $myBlogTitle, $myBlogText)
{
    $uri = 'https://www.blogger.com/feeds/' . $gBlogId . '/posts/default';
    $entry = $gData->newEntry();
    $entry->title = $gData->newTitle($myBlogTitle);
    $content = $gData->newContent($myBlogText);
    $content->setType('text');
    $entry->content = $content;
    $entryResult = $gData->insertEntry($entry, $uri);
    //$idText = split('-', $entryResult->id->text);
    //$newPostID = $idText[2];
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    } else {
        header("location:*my_website_link*");
    }
    //return $newPostID;
}

function getBlogId($gData, $feed)
{
    $query = new Zend_Gdata_Query($feed);
    $feed = $gData->getFeed($query);
    preg_match('/blog-([0-9]+)/', $feed->id->text, $match);
    if (isset($match[1]))
    {
        return $match[1];
    }
    return false;
}
$gData = new Zend_Gdata($client);
$gBlogId = getBlogId($gData, 'http://'.$blogUrl.'/feeds/posts/default');
createPublishedPost($gData, $gBlogId, $blogTitle, $blogText);
```

Comment: This doesn't actually explain what the issue was or help others with the same problem. It's unlikely anyone can simply copy/paste a proprietary sample of code without some explanation of the underlying problem and why this fixes it.